# Window manager affects 3d performance - how to work around it?

Tags: performance, window-manager, 3d

I learned the hard way that enabling compositing VM will affect 3d performance. What can I do today to be able play games on linux with no performance penalty? I guess I could create user with different WM, but I don't want to loose other user X session. Can I 'hibernate' it somehow? What are my options?

Comment: Which desktop are you using?

Comment: @wilf I had this issue with Gnome Shell, Unity and Cinnamon under respective gdm or lightdm, went back to openbox/lightdm to see giant performance boost (from 20 to 60 fps). Openbox is okay, but sometimes not so 'smart' in some areas and I kinda feel locked to it.

Comment: XFCE might work for you, has a decent compositing built in with a minimal performance hit. KDE is not bad either. Other then that, change the video card ?